# stuck with javascript-html output

Tags: javascript

I am kind of stuck in weird problem. i cant find the problem with the following code

```
 <html>
    <head>

<script type="text/javascript">

    // Import GET Vars
   document.$_GET = [];
   var urlHalves = String(document.location).split('?');
   if(urlHalves[1]){
      var urlVars = urlHalves[1].split('&');
      for(var i=0; i<=(urlVars.length); i++){
         if(urlVars[i]){
            var urlVarPair = urlVars[i].split('=');
            document.$_GET[urlVarPair[0]] = urlVarPair[1];
         }
      }
   }


    var tag_tag=document.$_GET['tags'];
    alert(tag_tag);

document.getElementById("resultElem4").innerHTML=tag_tag;


</script>
</head>

<body>
<p id='resultElem4'></p>


</body>
</html>
```

its showing the string in alert but not in html when i call it like result.php?tags=cat

Answer (score 0):

Put your script tag at the bottom (right before the closing *body* tag).  The issue is that the element *resultElem4* hasn't loaded when you try to reference it using *getElementById*.

Answer (score 0):

You just move the `< script >` to the end of the body.

```
<body><p></p><script>....</script></body>
```